# C++ embedded python PyArg_ParseTuple fails with string args

Tags: c++, python, unicode, decode

I'm trying to add embedded python to a OpenGL/SDL application.
So far everything works fine, like entering a string via SDL keyboard events and executing it with the embedded python interpreter.
I'm now into adding functions to call C/C++ functions like

```
void set_iterations(int c);
```

is invoked on the python interpreter with

```
>>> test.iterations(23)
```

The parsing of the integer parameter works like charm

```
static PyObject* test_iterations(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {  
    int iterations;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"i",&iterations);
    set_iterations(iterations);

    return Py_None;
}
```

But when I try this: `>>> test.addignore('something')`

```
static PyObject* test_addignore(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

        char* ignorestring;
        //PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"s",ignorestring);
        PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"s",&ignorestring);
        add_global_ignore(ignorestring); // C function

        return Py_None;
}
```

Python gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: invalid data
```

The string should be UTF-8, as SDL is set to grab UNICODE from the keyboard, and everything else works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea on what I might be doing wrong here?

I also inspected the args object passed to the function with

```
std::string args_str;

PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(args);
if (repr != NULL) {
    args_str = PyBytes_AsString(PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "Error"));
    Py_DECREF(repr);
}
std::cout << args_str << "\n";
```

And it gives me this: `('somestring',)`

---

Solution:
The error pointed out by rodrigo, was originally causing be believe that my debug code that should print the resulting string as PyObject was wrong. But the problem was that I was passing the parser the wrong pointer, leading to said undefined behaviour in the memory and therefore leading me to believe the parser was the problem.
The occurring last parser error was then the debug output itself, which was pointing to the wrong memory address. 
Thanks rodrigo, since your answer lead to solving the problem: accepted. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: What version of Python are you on? Did you try `test.addignore(u'something')`?

Comment: yes it tried u'string' - gives the same error. I'm on python3.1

Comment: You dont DECREF args after PyArg_ParseTuple()?

Comment: Your call to PyUnicode_AsEncodedString saved my day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
static PyObject* test_addignore(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    char* ignorestring;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"s", &ignorestring)) //Note the &
        return NULL;                                //Never ignore errors
    add_global_ignore(ignorestring);

    Py_RETURN_NONE;  //Always use helper macros
}
```

Comment: It's parsing `args`, not `ignorestring`, so how would this give a `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: ignorestring is of type char*, when I add an ampersand before that I rereference the char* to char** whereas PyArg_ParseTuple expects a char* when parsing a string. But the actual error occurs during the parsing of args, not during writing the ignorestring.

Comment: Actually, it expects the address of a char*, hence the &. From the doc: "You must not provide storage for the string itself; a pointer to an existing string is stored into the character pointer variable whose address you pass."

Comment: @agf Since the function will interpret the char* passed as a char**, unidefined behaviour is invoked, and anything can happen.

Comment: it expects a char*. which ignorestring is. &ignorestring is a char**

Comment: When you specify "i", you want an int, so you pass an int*. When you specify "s", you want a 'char*', so you pass a char**.

Comment: okay, it expects a char**. My bad. BUT that does not solve the problem, as the problem occurs during parsing of the args.

Comment: So, I updated the question code to match the char** correction. But the original error persists.